# Using a function closes pygame window

Tags: python, pygame, crash, pygame-surface

The following is the `String` class. Using the draw function from this class in my main loop immediately closes the game without any errors and as long i dont include it, the game runs fine. It does give me the following warning.

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\rahul\OneDrive\Documents\A level python codes\shootingGame.py", line 44
    D.blit(self.player, (self.pos[0], self.pos[1]))
DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float).  Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.
```

---

```
import math, sys, os, pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display
D = win.set_mode((1200, 600))

class String:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.pos = [x, y]
        self.dx = 0
        self.dy = 0
        self.string = pygame.Surface((1, 1)).convert_alpha()
        self.string.fill((0, 255, 0))

    def draw(self):
        angle = pygame.transform.rotate(self.string, (player.orbital_angle))
        length = math.hypot(self.dx, self.dy)
        self.string = pygame.Surface((3, length))
        D.blit(angle, (self.pos[0], self.pos[1]))

string = String(600, 300)
While True:
    string.draw()
```

I initially had everything in `draw` function in differnet functions but it got a bit messy while debugging.Specifically, it is the last two lines in `draw()` that's causing the window to crash i.e

```
self.string = pygame.Surface((3, length))
D.blit(angle, (self.pos[0], self.pos[1]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position (*dest*) argument to [`pygame.Surface.blit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) is ought to be a tuple of 2 integral numbers.
In your case `self.pos[0]` and/or `self.pos[1]` seems to be a floating point number.

You can get rid of the warning by rounding the floating point coordinates to integral coordinates ([`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round)):

```py
D.blit(self.player, (round(self.pos[0]), round(self.pos[1])))
```

For the sake of completeness it has to be mentioned that the argument can also be a rectangle. A tuple with the 4 components (left, top, width, height).

---

Furthermore you have create a Surface with an integral length and you have to rotate the surface after it is (re)created:

```py
class String:
    # [...]
   
    def draw(self):

        # compute INTEGRAL length        
        length = math.hypot(self.dx, self.dy)
        length = max(1, int(length))

        # create surface
        self.string = pygame.Surface((1, length)).convert_alpha()
        self.string.fill((0, 255, 0))

        # roatet surface
        angle = pygame.transform.rotate(self.string, player.orbital_angle)

        # blit rotated surface
        D.blit(angle, (round(self.pos[0]), round(self.pos[1])))
```